# C# Compiler error with Substring

Tags: c#

Why I'm getting:

```
Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: length
```

when I compile this code:
http://pastebin.com/CW4EcCM8

some part of it:

```
    public string findFileEnding(string file)
    {
        int index1 = file.IndexOf('.');
        file = file.Substring(index1, file.Length);
        return file;
    }
```

Thanks;)

Comment: There's no check that index1 is > -1 (That there was even a . in the string).  If you do a substring w/ index:-1 it throws that error too...

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but a more reliable way to find a file extension is to use the Path class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.aspx

Comment: @Rikon Same error, but with a different message...

Comment: To expand on @CoreyOgburn's comment, you'd want to look at the [GetExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension.aspx) method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am thinking there is a chance `Path.GetExtension` could be something OP might want instead.

notice that it returns extension with `.` like `.exe`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The second argument to `Substring`, if present, is the desired length of the substring. So you're asking for a string the same length as `file` but starting at a position possibly different from 0. This would make the end of your substring to be past the end of `file`.

Assuming you want to get all of `file` starting at position `index1`, you can just leave out the second argument altogether:

```
file = file.Substring(index1);
```

To make this robust, you'll want to put in a few more checks:

1. `file` may be `null`.
2. The return value of `IndexOf` may be `-1`. This would happen if `file` does not contain a dot.

Comment: May want to mention that the OP should also check for `IndexOf` returning -1.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a compiler error, that's a runtime error.

Note the documentation for `String.Substring(int, int)`:

> Retrieves a substring from this instance. The substring starts at a specified character position [`startIndex`] and has a specified length [`length`].

So the **substring** will have the specified length. Therefore, there must be enough characters starting at `startIndex` to return a substring of the specified length. Therefore, the following inequalities must be satisfied for `String.Substring` to succeed on an instance `s` of `string`:

```
startIndex >= 0
length >= 0
length > 0 implies startIndex + length <= s.Length
```

Note that if you just want a substring from `index` to the end of the string, you can say

```
s.Substring(index);
```

Here, the only constraint is

```
startIndex>= 0
startIndex < s.Length
```

Answer (score 0):

You would want to do something like this:

```
public string FindFileEnding(string file)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(file))
    {
        // Either throw exception or handle the file here
        throw new ArgumentNullException();
    }
    try
    {
        return file.Substring(file.LastIndexOf('.'));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Handle the exception here if you want, or throw it to the calling method
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume you meant `string.IsNullOrEmpty(file)` for you the first if-statement, as what you have is not valid unless you've defined a custom extension method. You should also check `LastIndexOf`'s return value. Rethrowing that exception would not makes sense.

Comment: @CodeNaked Thanks for the code check, hard to do just in the browser. There any sites that validate C# for you? Its not meant to be the complete answer, just a starting point. And if the last index isn't valid then you'll have to handle it either before or after. I originally had it with `int index = file.LastIndexOf('.')` but removed it as there was nothing stating how they wanted to handle errors or bad values

Comment: I'm not aware of any sites that do it, but there are some [lightweight tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2775055/looking-for-replacement-for-snippet-compiler).